# Why does a file upload response's Content-Type have to be HTML?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I just noticed something today while working on a HTML file upload form. I'm testing my server-side processing function (Image conversion & compression) with a REST Client (Postman in my case).

If PHP sets the response's `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, the 200KB response takes around 30 seconds to be processed (after the request has returned), but if I set it to `text/html`, it's done right away in less than a second after the request is completed.

I'm happy that I can make it work, but my curiosity got the best of me, and now I want to know **why** HTML Content-Type is required. Anyone knows ?

Comment: What is processing the response?  PHP does not change the header, the header is generated by the sending server. I am guessing the delay is before you receive the response.  Also assume you specify the type in your request.

Comment: I'm using a REST Client, but the same can be observed with a form sent with Javascript. In PHP you can set the Content-Type of the response, this is what I'm doing

Comment: In PHP you can set the Content Type in YOUR HTTP Response Header. 

You can request a client to return it's Response in a particular Content Type. 

But it makes no sense to change  the received Header.  After all the purpose of the Content Type is to inform the user agent what format the response is in. 

Once you receive it, you all ready know and changing it serves no purpose. 

Where in the process does your PHP play a role?

Comment: Using a Javascript form (or a REST Client) I send an image to PHP, to be converted to JPEG, compressed, encoded to base64, and I return the base64 image along with its properties (filename, dimensions) in a JSON object. Since I write my response object manually (I need a specific status code), I set the content type initially to `application/json` then to `text/html` to test and I found that it worked